# Flattening faces while keeping model shape

Tags: modeling, workflow, faces

I am trying to flatten a lot but not all these faces and maintaining the detail of the model. I have tried the add-on in loop-tools, which of course just pulls the surrounding faces so you end up chasing yourself around the model.

I have also tried <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> in the "Normal" setting but again it pulls the surrounding faces. Any help or suggestions would be great.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome, have you tried the Smooth tool?

Comment: Hey Emir. No I have not. Is there anyway when i flatten using the looptool I can somehow lock that face so it doesn't move when I go to flatten the adjacent faces?

Comment: Try to hide that face (H)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the "decimate" modifier with the option "Planar" set to a high angle limit.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your message haarigertroll. Iv had no luck with the decimate. It seems like a really simple thing I'm trying to achieve. Can't believe its taking me so long to find a solution. 